# Systemd timer running scheduled service 2 times in a row, instead of running only 1 time

Tags: debian, systemd, systemd-timer

I have a nodejs gui program (does not requires user interaction), which needs to be run at every 40th minutes at each hour. Say run at 05:40PM, 06:40PM, 07:40PM and so on. In a Debian server, I have enabled a systemd timer using:

```
systemctl --user enable my_program.timer
```

Problem is, scheduling starts at the given time and finishes successfully. But immediately after that program starts again and finishes successfully.

Say program started at 5:40PM and finished at 5:45PM. After a minute or so, say at 5:46PM program starts again and finishes. Then this happens again at next time, so at 6:40PM.

This happens every time every hour. Also, if I reboot the server, after logging into that user account, program starts immediately instead of waiting 5 minute.

1. How to stop auto running second time?
2. How to force to start 5 minutes after reboot?

Content of `/home/user/schedule.sh`

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
cd /home/user/my_program && DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/node ./index.js
```

Content of `/home/user/.config/systemd/user/my_program.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=My Program

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/schedule.sh
```

Content of `/home/user/.config/systemd/user/my_program.timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=My Program Timer
Requires=my_program.service

[Timer]
Unit=my_program.service
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:40:*
OnBootSec=5 minutes

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Comment: `OneBootSec` should be `OnBootSec`.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Thanks, changed it. But still after reboot, starts immediately.

Comment: Try `OnBootSec=5min`.

Comment: @ajgringo619 no change, still starts immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's focus on one question here: the duplicate runs each hour. You've used this syntax for it:

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:40:*
```

According to `man systemd.time`, the wildcard in the seconds place means it matches every second of the 40th minute of every hour. You can confirm this with the included `systemd-analyze` tool, which has a calendar sub-command:

```
systemd-analyze calendar --iterations=5 "*-*-* *:40:*"
Normalized form: *-*-* *:40:*
    Next elapse: Thu 2020-12-17 17:40:00 EST
       (in UTC): Thu 2020-12-17 22:40:00 UTC
       From now: 15min left
       Iter. #2: Thu 2020-12-17 17:40:01 EST
       (in UTC): Thu 2020-12-17 22:40:01 UTC
       From now: 15min left
       Iter. #3: Thu 2020-12-17 17:40:02 EST
       (in UTC): Thu 2020-12-17 22:40:02 UTC
       From now: 15min left
       Iter. #4: Thu 2020-12-17 17:40:03 EST
       (in UTC): Thu 2020-12-17 22:40:03 UTC
       From now: 15min left
       Iter. #5: Thu 2020-12-17 17:40:04 EST
       (in UTC): Thu 2020-12-17 22:40:04 UTC
       From now: 15min left
```

So that's a problem.

The second problem is that you have included `Requires=` in your timer. In `man systed.unit`, the documentation for the `Requires=` directive says this:

> If this unit gets activated, the units listed [In Requires=] will be activated as well.

So that could also cause the target service to be loaded a second time as well.

Open a new question about `OnBootSec=` timing-- that's a separate issue.

Comment: Using `OnCalendar=*-*-* *:40:00` and removed `Requires=` from timer. And it solved both problems.